Identifying a TNG episode where Dr. Pulaski instructs another doctor on a sling
I can't recall what episode I saw this from- basically when a doctor under Pulaski tells her some equipment in Sick Bay isn't working right she tells him to put a patient's arm in a sling.
When he admits he doesn't know what a sling is and she explains it to him, he considers the concept primitive and backward (not his exact words but the general sentiment).

This is Season 2, Episode 11 - Contagion.
Here is the relevant quote -

MEDIC: I've got a problem here. The knitter isn't working.
PULASKI: Try a splint.
MEDIC: Doctor?
PULASKI: Splint. It's a very ancient concept. You take two flat pieces
of wood or plastic, a bandage. The broken limb is kept immobile.
DOCTOR: That's crazy, that's not practicing medicine.

Full Transcript can be found here.
